# set text of input element with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

hi i have a element like below:

```
<input id="txt_search" class="search-box tp-co-1 tp-pa-rl-5 tp-re tp-bo-bo" type="text" placeholder="جستجوی سهم" onmouseup="this.select();" autocomplete="off">
```

I want to set text of this element to something

so I use below code

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "txt_search")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','something')", element)
```

so then it should appear a dropdownlist like below but it doesnot

```
<div id="list_dropdown"><div isin="IRO1PIAZ0001" symbol="غاذر1 - کشت‌وصنعت‌پیاذر"><span></span><span style="color: red;">غاذر</span><span>1 - کشت‌وصنعت‌پیاذر</span></div></div>
```

so then i must select first item of this dropdownlist

this is what i want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the code you need, but there's no reason to use `browser.execute_script` unless the standard `element.send_keys` function does not work as expected. Use the below code which leverages your existing code and `send_keys` function:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "txt_search")))

element.send_keys("something")
```

Comment: hi thanks it returns error that says "element not interactable"@Christine

Comment: when I write something in it a dropdownlist appears and i select first item of it

Comment: Try changing `presence_of_element_located` to `element_to_be_clickable` - updated my example to reflect this.

Comment: thanks but it returns this error raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)@Christine

Comment: hi martin can you help me?@MartijnPieters

Comment: hi Stéphane sorry i take your time@StéphanePiette

Comment: hi christine i update my question thanks a lot @Christine

Comment: it has on mouse up event in it@Christine